# Ktor java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/ktor/server/cio/CIO

Tags: kotlin, gradle, ktor

I developed a simple project using ktor

here is my `Application.kt`

```
fun main() {

embeddedServer(
    factory = CIO, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0"
) {
    configDependencyInjection()
    configSerialization()
    configJwtAuthentication()
    configStatusPages()
    configRequestValidation()

    configUserRouting()


    Database.connect(
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/coffeehouse",
        driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",
        user = "postgres",
        password = "74279744fz"
    )

    transaction {
        SchemaUtils.drop(Users, CoffeeHouses)
        SchemaUtils.create(Users, CoffeeHouses)
    }

}.start(wait = true)
}
```

and here is my `build.gradle.kts`

```
val ktorVersion: String by project
val kotlinVersion: String by project
val logbackVersion: String by project
val exposedVersion: String by project
val koinVersion: String by project
val postgresVersion: String by project

plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.20"
    id("io.ktor.plugin") version "2.1.2"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.7.20"
}

group = "ir.coffee"
version = "0.0.1"
application {
    mainClass.set("ir.coffee.ApplicationKt")

    val isDevelopment: Boolean = project.ext.has("development")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dio.ktor.development=$isDevelopment")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-class"] = application.mainClass
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json-jvm:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-cio-jvm:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth-jwt:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-request-validation:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-status-pages:$ktorVersion")

    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logbackVersion")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:$exposedVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:$exposedVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:$exposedVersion")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:$postgresVersion")


    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-ktor:$koinVersion")
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-logger-slf4j:$koinVersion")

    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm:$ktorVersion")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVersion")

}
```

when I run the project, it works fine and i can make a `jar` file with
`./gradlew installDist` command.

but when I try to run the `jar` file with `java -jar ir.coffee-0.0.1.jar` command
i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/ktor/server/cio/CIO
at ir.coffee.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:16)
at ir.coffee.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.ktor.server.cio.CIO at         
   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 2 more
```

any suggestion how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `installDist` task packs the project's class files in a JAR without dependencies. So to solve your problem you can either specify paths to the dependencies via the `-classpath` flag while executing `java` or pack all dependencies in a JAR ([Gradle Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)).

Comment: I used `java -cp 'ir.coffee-0.0.1.jar:lib/*' ir.coffee.ApplicationKt` and still got the same error!